# php - html: Cant load a date value in form

Tags: php, html, forms, ultimate-member

I use a registration form from Ultimate Member plugin, in which each user gives his birthday. The field is saved as d/m/Y (ex. 17/11/1995) with a metakey named "birthday" in usermeta table. After this registration, each user can sumbit other forms in my site (which i create manually with html). In these forms i use autofill mode from the registration data by using:

```
value="<?php echo um_user('birthday');?>"
```

So with this way, if someone has already provided the data that the form needs in his registration, it is already written in the appropriate field.

```
<label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
<input type="date" id="birthday" value="<?php echo um_user('birthday');?>" name="birthday" required>
```

The problem is that the date is not filled with the data provided in registration, although other data types do normally. I tried to solve this by using `type="datetype"` and it works, but i cant control the input with this type.

Any ideas? (I prefer solutions with php or html because im not familiar with Javascript).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My gut instinct is that `um_user('birthday')` is not a text object. Try debugging with `gettype(um_user('birthday'))`;

Comment: It is a string. Shouldn't it be a string? I solved the problem though, but just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to format the date for the value attribute to be accepted.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date
"value: A DOMString representing a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty"

Comment: this is the correct answer. your date is formatted as 17/11/1995, you must set it as 1995-11-17

Comment: It works! I saved the data in this format "Y-m-d" and it is shown correctly now as autofilled. Thank you very much guys, both of you.